# Making Libertine's ligatures work with pdfLaTeX and Cyrillic characters

Tags: pdftex, ligatures, cyrillic, libertine

I have a problem with typesetting Libertine's ligatures using pdfLaTex, which, by some experimentation, I have localised to the following three lines of code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
```

The T2A encoding is used, because I need a way to display Cyrillic characters.

The problem itself is, the ligatures do not work: pdfLaTex renders them like
[image: incorrect ligatures with pdfLaTex]

while LuaLaTex and XeLaTex both produce
[image: correct ligatures with LuaLaTex and XeLaTex]

Libertine's CTAN documentation does say about features unavailable to pdfLaTeX, but common English ligatures are not one of them. Moreover, everything seems to work everywhere when I do not require T2A as an encoding. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you sure you need to set `T2A` option under pdfLaTeX just to display cyrillic characters? It would seem that this option causes the ff, fi, fl, ffi, and ffl ligature not to get active under pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico There’s no absolutely strong requirement for pdfLaTeX, but it is preferred for being much gentler with my computing resources and compiling more than twice as fast. I suppose I do not yet need advanced scripting features that come with other options. Besides, It would just be interesting to understand why some things work and others don’t.

Comment: you should use T1 encoding when you write latin, switch to T2A only for the cyrillic parts.

Comment: @MikeLand My recommendation is to use LuaTeX when you can and PDFTeX when you have to. The old 8-bit fonts from last century work less well, are more complicated, and aren’t compatible with anything else. One nice feature you’ll get with `babel` on LuaTeX: you can type in Cyrillic and it will just work, including changing the language for you and hyphenating correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}` will make T1 encoding the default.  Then use

`{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont ... }` for cyrillic text.

Comment: Even better, load `babel` and get hyphenation.

Comment: I just tried this because I needed some cyrillic text but it created (of all things) type 3 MetaFont glyphs for CMR… This is TeXLive 2016.

Comment: So update your TeXLive .